# How to export normalMap instead of bumpMap with three.js Blender plugin

Tags: three.js

I'm using the three.js Blender exporter plugin (83dev) to export a model as json and am loading it into three.js (83dev) using the ObjectLoader.

I've created a normal texture in Blender and assigned an influence of Geometry:Normal.

Here are the three.js export options I'm using:

[image]

However, when exporting the json it is included like so:

```
"materials":[{
    "vertexColors":0,
    "bumpMap":"D5F9A3C3-48D7-4D1A-9F82-C56A03EE26A6",
    "depthWrite":true,
    "type":"MeshPhongMaterial",
    "specular":1644825,
    "color":13421772,
    "depthTest":true,
    "name":"material_0",
    "map":"F5BE3F62-D7ED-42CF-B92E-A2243B2EF88F",
    "blending":"NormalBlending",
    "emissive":0,
    "bumpScale":[1,1],
    "uuid":"4808DEC3-ABAC-4422-B9C0-2D1388370D51",
    "shininess":1
}],
```

(bumpMap, bumpScale).

The normal map has no effect unless I change these to normalMap and normalScale.

Is this a bug with the exporter/three.js, or am I missing an option in Blender?

Answer (score 0):

Answered on the three.js github: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10602#issuecomment-273867816

On the Texture tab under 'Image Sampling' check 'Normal Map'.